# Force Install .NET 4.8.1 on Server 2016

Tags: .net-framework, windows-server-2016

Server 2016 supports .NET 4.8.0.

It does not support 4.8.1.

There are very few changes between 4.8.0 and 4.8.1, so I struggle to believe that this is a fundamental limitation and that 4.8.1 couldn't run just fine on Server 2016, I think MS have just blocked the install to force people to upgrade their OS.

Is there a way to bypass this and install .NET 4.8.1 on Server 2016?

Comment: no; There is no way to bypass the restriction. The reason .NET Framework 4.8.1 even support(s) the versions of Windows it supports, is because its built-into those versions, Windows Server 2016 is built-upon the Windows 10 NT kernel (a specific version of Windows 10). Is there a reason you believe you need to install .NET Framework 4.8.1? Unless the application has a configuration file that specifically indicates it's only compatible with .NET Framework 4.8.1 then you should be able to run the application. However, i might be underestimating, the differences also.

Comment: I have 4.8.0.xxx on up to date Windows 10 VM and a bit higher on up to date Windows 11 4.8.0.yyy .  So in addition to @Ramhound’s post, do you have a user audience for the more advanced version?

Comment: FWIW, I checked Windows 11 Insider (25281.1000) and .NET is 4.8.0.zzz

Comment: Please provide your reasons for needing 4.8.1 so we can help you further.

Comment: The reason I want to have 4.8.1 is becaues we want to target our app to the latest version of the framework. If it's not possible to bypass the restriction, then we'll just have to target 4.8 until we can upgrade our IaaS estate. Although I'm not sure I buy the "its built-into those versions" argument, given it's installable from an executable and the dotnet framework is essentially just a bunch of dlls. I don't think 4.8.1 targests any windows APIs that 4.8.0 doesn't, so I'm fairly sure this is just an arbitrary restriction from MS

Comment: @ScottishTapWater just arrived at the same problem. Did you ever find a solution, or just live with M$'s limitations?

Comment: @Brondahl - Unfortunately, had to just deal with it til our IAAS estate got upgraded

Comment: Fair. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be tempting to try to install .NET Framework 4.8.1 on Windows Server 2016, it's important to note that Microsoft has introduced specific enhancements and features in .NET 4.8.1 that are designed to support legacy .NET applications on the ARM architecture. These enhancements were specifically introduced in conjunction with Windows Server 2022.
If your application needs to run on Windows Server 2016, it's advisable to target .NET Framework 4.8 instead of 4.8.1. The added support for ARM architecture is a feature that is only available in Server 2022, and attempting to install 4.8.1 on Server 2016 makes no sense as there is no support for ARM architecture.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Removing

```
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
```

from application configuration file helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).